# iDangero.us Swiper image gallery with thumbnails doesn't respond to 'click' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm using idangero.us Swiper on my website to display images gallery with thumbs. So, I have some radio inputs with 'data-image-id's which contain a reference to swiper's gallery thumbnails. These thumbs contain id="product-image-id-##" (## - any number).

So it's supposed to change displayed image via clicking this radio inputs, as it was clicked thumbnail. I have next code for this:

```js
this.form.find(".skus input[type=radio]").click(function () {
  if ($(this).data('image-id')) {
    $("#product-image-" + $(this).data('image-id')).click();
  }
}
```

And next code for gallery:

```html
<div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div id="product-image-01" class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="product-image-02" class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="product-image-03" class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="product-image-04" class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://www.picpedia.org/highway-signs/images/example.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, the problem is, that when I click on radio button, click "gets" to the gallery's thumbnails, but not responded by gallery so image doesn't change.
How to make Swiper's thumbnails respond to 'click' event initiated by clicking on radio input via jQuery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: verify that `this` is what you want to point to... also I don't see any DOM elements on your HTML code with the class `.skus`

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've showed just a part of code because whole page contains too much of it. First code reaches DOM-elements with id="product-image-##" easily, i.e. if I use 'addClass' instead of 'click' it will execute normally. The problem is that Swiper gallery's thumbs do not respond exactly to 'click' event.

Comment: In addition to say, if I click to thumb with mouse it works okay, image changes to selected. Bu if I try to simulate 'click' via jQuery there's no reaction.